# Big O notation of pseudocode

Tags: runtime, big-o

I am having trouble determining the runtime of the following pseudocode.

```
while n > 0 do
  n = n/3
```

It seems to be rather straight forward, but I keep confusing myself would it be log<sub>3</sub>n?
I know that if it was dividing by two, it would be log<sub>2</sub>n.

The three is just throwing me off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base of the logarithm is not included in big-O notation, since changing bases is simply a scalar multiple. So it's just *O*(log *n*).